# R - Infer legend details from variable

Tags: r, plot

It's my first question on SO. Hopefully it will be enough detail:

I've made a Kaplan-Meier plot and would like to add a legend, however I am not having much luck with it. I know how to make a legend when you know which line is representative of it's respective category. Unfortunately since I'm using a large data set I don't know which line is which, and therefore am having a hard time creating the legend manually. Is there any way R can infer which category is which colour on the following graph? (The current selections aren't right in the legend, I was just guessing)

```
    kmsurv1 <- survfit(Surv(as.numeric(time),hydraulic)~type)
# Specify axis options within plot() 
plot(kmsurv1, col=c(1:12), main="Hydraulic Breakdown of Vehicles", sub="subtitle", xlab="Time", ylab="Probability of Being Operational", xlim=c(15400, 16500),ylim=c(.6,1.0))
legend("bottomleft", inset = 0, title = "Vehicle Type",legend= c("Hitachi Backhoe","Transport Trucks", "Water Trucks","Cat D8 Dozers", "D10 Dozers")
       ,fill = c(1:12), horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: you might consider looking into ggplot2, it's really flexible. But you could add a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a bit unsure of what you mean by "reproducible example?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like gglot2 doesn't support survfit...

Comment: so kmsurv1 is not a data frame?

Comment: take a look at this example http://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-a-legend-to-a-plot/ it should help you to do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `survival` package. The package document specifies that with `print(obj)`, the order of printout is the order in which they plot. You can then extract those names with `rownames(summary(sfit)$table)`. Just make sure that the colors you choose are in the same order in the `plot` and `legend` lines. Here's an example:

```
library(survival)
sfit <- survfit(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ sex, mgus1, subset=(enum==1))
print(sfit) # the order of printout is the order in which they plot
plot(sfit, col=1:4)
legend("topleft",legend=rownames(summary(sfit)$table),col=1:4, lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I found an extremely easy answer from: http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_surv

```
    install.packages('ggfortify')
    install.packages("ggplot2")
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggfortify)

    fit <- survfit(Surv(as.numeric(time),hydraulic)~type, data = mydata)
autoplot(fit,xlim = c(15000,16500))
```

[My Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtHLU.png)

Thank you to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396821/mlavoie for pointing me in the right direction.